# JWT Token not generated after successful Authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I created two filters to run for every request JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter and JwtTokenVerifier. I have used these two filters before and they HAVE worked. I think the main issue is with my Spring Security Config. When I debug these two filters only JwtTokenVerified is recognized and JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter does not get called at all. When I make a request from PostMan with a application/json content type the server would give me an error:

`class path resource [templates/logIn.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

/logIn Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logIn",method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public void login(){
    }
```

Spring Security Config

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private SecureUserDaoService secureUserDaoService;
    private JwtConfig jwtConfig;
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()

                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

                .and()

                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfig, secretKey))
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(secretKey, jwtConfig), JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter.class)

                .authorizeRequests()

                .antMatchers("/accountPage", "/accountSettings").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/", "/signUp", "/logIn").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()

                .formLogin()
                .failureUrl("/")
                .successForwardUrl("/accountPage");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(secureUserDaoService);
        return provider;
    }
```

github [repo](https://github.com/NikitaNova/BasicCrudApp/tree/master/src/main/java/com/crudapp)

UPDATE:

By calling "/login" instead of "/logIn" in the client made it work, because apparently even when I add .loginPage("/logIn") AND .logInProcessingUrl("/logIn").It seems like spring still does not recognize my custom login controller when it goes through the filter chain. Feel free to comment below if you know of a better solution

Comment: Okay so I have added a .loginPage("/logIn") to my formLogIn settings but when I make a request with request header Content-Type: application/json and store the username and password parameter in the body as JSON. It gives me an error that the user was not found because the retreiveUser() method in DaoAuthenticationProvider.class was not given the username parameter. And again when I went through the error stack I found that the UsernameAndPassword filter was not called

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I edited my post and found some sort of solution. Though its not the kind I would have liked to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I debug these two filters only JwtTokenVerified is recognized and
> JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter does not get called at all.

`JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter` is being called. To prove it, either put a debug statement in your filter or better, in your `SecurityConfig.java`, enable `Spring Security debugger`, like so:

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
```

and you will see this:

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtUsernameAndPasswordFilter            // This is your filter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  JwtTokenVerifier                        // This is your filter
  DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter
  DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

> When I make a request from PostMan with a application/json content
> type the server would give me an error:
>
> class path resource [templates/logIn.html] cannot be opened because it
> does not exist

This is because in your `/templates` folder, there is no `logIn.html`.

> By calling "/login" instead of "/logIn" in the client made it work,
> because apparently even when I add .loginPage("/logIn") AND
> .logInProcessingUrl("/logIn").It seems like spring still does not
> recognize my custom login controller when it goes through the filter
> chain. Feel free to comment below if you know of a better solution

`/login` works because since you did not define a custom login page in your SecurityConfig.java, Spring Security will redirect you to its *default* login page.

If you do not want that feature, you can customize the `loginPage` as follows:

```
.and()
.formLogin().loginPage("/customizeMe")   // Your custom login page here
.failureUrl("/")
.successForwardUrl("/accountPage");
```